# YouTube Data API quota usage has become 0

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are developing software that uses the YouTube Data API.

Even though we haven't changed the implementation, the quota usage suddenly went to 0 from May 20th.

You can still use the YouTube Data API, but does anyone know about this strange phenomenon?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your quota says 0 its because google has disabled the api in your project. My contacts at google have been unclear why some projects get their quota removed. The only solution is to apply for an extension.  I have personally had projects with a YouTube data api quota of 0 on a project I just created.  If I then create another new project then I will get the 10k quota.

You need quota to make requests, if you are using up all your quota then just apply for an extension.  If your quota is 0 then you need quota apply for an extension.

Issue forum

- [Quota limit is 0](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208842985)
- [Quota 0](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/211012781)

[image]

Comment: I checked my project and the YouTube Data API status is enabled.
Also, the quota limit is not set to 0 and the limit has not been reached.

I apologize for the lack of clarity in my explanation.
I would like to know why Queries are 0 even though I am using the API.