# Youtube API Quota is Zero

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use youtube api to collect some data for a project. To do this, I was generating accessToken using a microservice with refresh token that I get from the email account. But, Whenever I use the generated token, i get a response saying that I have maxed my quota. I checked my quota stats in the GCP account I could see that the quota was set to zero. I was wondering if someone could help me in updating this.

Thanks

Comment: @K.Nicholas What exactly does the YouTube api have to do with marketing?

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK [YouTube Data API v3 quota doesn't always work perfectly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72355518/7123660), maybe as a temporary solution you would be interested in my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API) no-key service hosted at https://yt.lemnoslife.com Indeed by fetching https://yt.lemnoslife.com/noKey/YOUR_REQUEST you will receive the same content as fetching https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/YOUR_REQUEST For instance as described by [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint, you can fetch in a free quota manner https://yt.lemnoslife.com/noKey/videos?part=snippet&id=VIDEO_ID